# What is the location of the temp file for OneDrive for business Sync

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

So I am trying to sync my onedrive for business with my PC. I have one single file and two empty folders on my OneDrive which is around 550 MB.
I have a 2 mbps connection and I am waiting for the file to be available in my PC.
But it's been 24 hours and I can see only the empty folders available but the file is still not available on my PC.

I checked the performance monitor and found Groovy.exe to be running and using network somewhere around 30 kbps.

I believe the file is being synced although the speed is extremely slow.

I just want to know what percentage of the file has been downloaded. OneDrive sync program just shows that one file is being synced but doesn't tell the progress.

I believe the file is being downloaded and kept in some temp location but couldn't find it after searching in App data folder.

Where does OneDrive "for business" keeps the temp file(the unfinished downloaded file)?

Comment: Try 1/ Browse to “Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\Spw” this is all related to groove, and spw equals SharePoint Workspace.
2/ Go to “Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\OfficeFileCache” and also delete all content from this folder. This is where all the caching from your files stored. Source https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/252276

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** Before playing around with cached copies, make sure that you have a backup for all the files that you have in OneDrive.

---

There are two locations that you need to check. One is the [Office Document Cache](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-Document-Cache-settings-4B497318-AE4F-4A99-BE42-B242B2E8B692).

**For Office 2013 (15.0)**

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Office\15.0\OfficeFileCache
```

**For Office 2016 (16.0)**

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OfficeFileCache
```

The other is the [SharePoint Workspace Cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_workspace_development_team/archive/2010/03/12/sharepoint-workspace-and-the-office-document-cache.aspx):

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Office\Spw
```

Comment: I'm happy my comment was useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

If groove.exe is active then you are not using the newest version of OneDrive, called "next generation."  It's a lot better but has a few limitations if you are doing certain things.

I would recommend checking if any of these limitations apply to you, and then upgrade to the latest version of OneDrive.

To answer your question, the path you are looking for is %localappdata%\microsoft\onedrive

The following link will tel you all about next gen OneDrive client, how to transition to it and where to download it. I highly recommend it.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-in-Windows-615391c4-2bd3-4aae-a42a-858262e42a49